# iAd not showing Any ads, Swift, ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, iad

when I run the game a white box appears at the top of the game which I'm guessing the ads are suppose to appear in there, but no ads ever appear!

Am I doing something wrong, missing a certain piece of code somewhere, or blind? haha.

I'm quite new to this iAd and everything!

Here is an image of it [image: Click here For Image]

Here is the ViewController Code!

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import iAd


class GameViewController: UIViewController, ADBannerViewDelegate{

@IBOutlet var Banner: ADBannerView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let scene = GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("GameScene") as? GameScene {
        // Configure the view.
        let skView = self.view as SKView
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

        skView.presentScene(scene)

        loadAds()
    }
}

func loadAds() {
    self.canDisplayBannerAds = true
    Banner = ADBannerView(frame: CGRect.zeroRect)
    Banner.center = CGPointMake(Banner.center.x, view.bounds.size.height - Banner.frame.size.height / 2)
    Banner.delegate = self
    Banner.hidden = true
    view.addSubview(Banner)
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {
    self.Banner.hidden = true
}

func bannerViewWillLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {

}

func bannerViewActionShouldBegin(banner: ADBannerView!, willLeaveApplication willLeave: Bool) -> Bool {
    return willLeave
}

func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
    self.Banner.hidden = false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are using `self.canDisplayBannerAds = true` in addition to creating an `ADBannerView` programmatically. Remove `self.canDisplayBannerAds = true` from your loadAds function.

Answer (score -1):

It seems to be working all of the sudden! Was getting error message, but it has gone away and the Ad has actually loaded! :)

Don't know what was going on!

Comment: If your problem can't be reproduced anymore I suggest you flag the question for closure using the appropriate close reason.